# How to suppress output in Sublime Text cmd?

Tags: windows, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

How can I suppress the output in Sublime Text Build System output?

I tried this but it says `Error: unrecognized or incomplete command line.`

```
{
    "cmd": ["ipconfig", ">nul 2>&1"],
    "name": "ipconfig",
    "shell": "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "name": "ipconfig",
    "shell_cmd": "ipconfig >nul 2>&1"
}
```

I always use shell_cmd because you can just write the command like you would on the command line instead of trying to figure out the multiple arguments nonsense in the array. This worked for me.